# How to open Excel 2007 (xlsx) file with CDaoDatabase

Tags: excel, odbc, dao, xlsx

Using CDaoDatabase defined in afxdao.h, how can I open up Excel 2007 (xlsx) files?  I can open up Excel 2003 (xls) files using the connection string Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1, anybody know how I can do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 as the provider. Not sure if DAO supports that. [MFC's DAO classes are deprecated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc811599.aspx).